# Gibt es eine Unterschied zwischen "bindend" und "verbindlich"?

Tags: difference

Zufällig komme ich auf den Gedanke, ob es eine Unterschied zwischen bindend und verbindlich gibt? Dann habe ich im Internet so einen Satz gefunden.
[enter link description here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/eine-bindende-zusage-ist-verbindlich.2828016/)

Eine bindende Zusage ist verbindlich.

Was bedeutet dieser Satz?

Comment: Das wird doch unter dem Link schon diskutiert. Ohne Kontext ist der Satz sinnlos, weil "verbindlich" und "bindend" Synonyme sind.

Answer (score 1):

[Bindend](https://www.dwds.de/wb/binden) in diesem Sinne als "zusammenhalten" verwendet
[Verbindlich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verbindlich) hier als "bindend, verpflichtend, gültig"

Gibt es Unterschiede? Absolut
Aber in deinem Beispiel nicht, der Satz könnte genau so gut "Der grüne Rasen ist grün." sein

Es würde ausreichen zu sagen "Die Zusage ist verbindlich" oder "Eine bindende Zusage"

Wenn du eine verbindliche Zusage zu etwas gibst dann bist du dazu verpflichtet dieser nachzukommen, z.B. du bestellst etwas online und bezahlst erst später, die Webseite wird dich dazu "zwingen" eine bindende Zusage zu erteilen (Button klicken).